# From [dll / lib / def / exp] to c/c++ header file

Tags: visual-studio, dll, header

I have a dynamic library compiled with visual studio.
(so 4 files: Library.dll, Library.lib, Library.def and Library.exp)

This dll contains exported classes and functions.

Is there a way to obtain C/C++ header files (.h) with these files?

Comment: Not sure if there are automatic ways, but you can write one yourself by looking at exports.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with Eugene, unless you're dealing with name mangled C++ calling convention -- and I'm not sure how easy it is in that case.  Chances are the exports are stdcall, which gives you the number of bytes in the param list but not the types.  What's 12?  Two ints and a pointer to float?  Twelve chars?  Ugly.  If it's CDECL, you don't even get that.  You might try doing dumpbin /all on the dll or dumbin /exports, though the latter will probably reflect what's in the def file.